# SSL https:// to https://www. redirect before privacy warning Magento

Tags: redirect, ssl, htaccess

I have just installed SSL on a server and am now trying to install it in Magento. I've put the base urls in SSL mode, and also changed the http:// to https:// to always use SSL even on product pages etc.

However, when my site is accessed from https:// Google Chrome throws a big fat warning sign that says privacy warning. I can't for the life of me find a solution around this problem to just redirect users to the https://www. version before the error message is thrown.

I'm very sure that there is a solution for this, as I have seen multiple websites just handle this perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks guys! This has been solved now. My SSL certificate didn't support the url of my site without the www. I have bought a new certificate with that url included and all is working fine now!

Answer (score 2):

may be you have not changed base secure url in mysql database.
try this :-

Method 1: change Magento base URLs in Magento administrator panel
Log into your Magento admininstrator panel.
On the top menu bar, click System > Configuration.
On the left menu, click Web.
Open the Unsecure and Secure dropdowns, locate the base URL line, and replace this with the new URL.  
Clear the Magento cache and your browser's cache. The site should load properly now.

Method 2: Change Magento base URLs with PHPMyAdmin
> MySQL > PhpMyAdmin.
You will be brought to the main menu for phpMyAdmin.  On the left side of the screen, locate and click the name of the Magento database corresponding to URL you want to change.   
You will see a list of all the tables in the database in alphabetical order.  
Search for the `core_config_data` table and click Browse.
Expand the viewing area of phpmyadmin. At the top and bottom in the main panel, locate the grey box and change the number of rows to a larger number, such as 100.
Locate the rows `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` and click Edit next to the corresponding lines.  Change the base URL to the intended string, and click OK.

Flush the Magento cache, and the site should load with the set base URLs properly now.

Method 3: Change Magento base URLs with the command line

Attention: Due to the possibility of irreparable damage, do not attempt to change the base URLs unless you are an experienced technician. 
s, execute the following commands:

Cmds:-

```
update core_config_data set value = 'http://domainname/' where path = 'web/unsecure/base_url';
update core_config_data set value = 'http://domainname/' where path = 'web/secure/base_url';
```

Answer (score 2):

You most likely have elements on your site that are not secure. You can use a 3rd party website such as [Why no padlock?](https://www.whynopadlock.com/) to track down the code that is responsible.

In my experience some modules that aren't very well written are hard codded to do `http://`.

Other areas could be `CSS`, a manually inserted link on your site that was written as `http://`.

Use the tool I provided to see where the issue is and correct as necessary.

Comment: The whole site is completely optimized for SSL. There are no unsafe urls linking to any image or other link, and for the https://www.sitename.com I get the green lock symbol in chrome so all seems well. However, when I try to access the page using only http://sitename.com I get the big error message in chrome and firefox.

Comment: Check you .htaccess file to make sure you've properly added the redirect to https. If that doesn't work are you using a shared hosting provider? What about Plesk / Virtualmin ect? The problem could be in the config. Let me know!

Answer (score 2):

By the sounds of it, what you actually need is a wildcard SSL. From what I can tell based on what you have said, you only have an SSL certificate for the www.* of your store. If you had a wildcard SSL certificate non-www would not throw an error in certain browsers.

Alternatively, if you do have a wildcard SSL, you'll want to check with the provider of the SSL on how to setup correctly on your server, or ask your web host to kindly take a look :)

If you post your apache vhost (or other webserver config like nginx..), then I can assist further.